# "If" vs "Only if" vs "If and only if"

Tags: meaning, phrases, logic

If I said:

> Yell only if I fall.

Would the person *have* to yell once I fell?

---

> **Sources of confusion**
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if#Distinction_from_.22if.22_and_.22only_if.22)
>   [This
>   guy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/answer-to-life-the-universe-and-everything/3031#3031)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Recall that in [*formal logic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic), your expressions are used as follows:

- *A* if *B* means that *B* implies *A*
- A only if B means that A implies B
- A if and only if B means that A is equivalent to B.

For example if in the morning I tell my wife:

> "*I'll buy that shirt we saw yesterday only if it costs less than 40 dollars*"

and she sees me wear it in the evening, she can *deduce* that I paid less than 40 dollars.

So, logically speaking, in your example, the deduction is that if a yell is heard, necessarily you fell:  no notion of obligation is involved.

However, human beings are not computer programs and the use of "*only if*" in real life is more subtle than what logicians might decree. Here is an example:

> It would be cruel for a father to tell his daughter "*I'll buy you
> this dress only if you get good grades at the end of the year*" and
> then buy nothing even though she had only A's.

You wouldn't have committed a logical error but would have shown you are a lousy parent!

Comment: This is why logicians use **iff** for 'if and only if'. I think it would be useful in real life, but can't see it catching on.

Comment: Your first shirt-buying example was very helpful.

Comment: In the last of your three logical expressions, I'd suggest replacing "A is equivalent to B" with "A implies B and B implies A". If you said that you'd buy the shirt **iff** it costs less than $40, then she'd know you bought the shirt if she saw that its price was less than $40 OR she'd know it cost less than $40 if she saw you wearing the shirt. (Well, assuming you'd wear the shirt **iff** you bought it. ;-)

Comment: Caleb, "A is equivalent to B" means exactly the same as the conjunction of "A implies B" and "B implies A" .

Comment: Georges, just wondering about your last example. Are you implying that getting only A's =/= good grades?
(Yes, I'm aware this is old, but I see you're still active)

Comment: @DarkLightA: no, I was using the A's  for emphasis and stylistic diversity. If you find that confusing, just replace what I wrote by "...and then buy nothing even though she had good grades. You wouldn't..."

Comment: Huh.. But in that logical statement isn't it saying that only in the case that she gets good grades will he buy her a dress. Therefore, when she gets good grades, he will buy her a dress, logically. According to my interpretation, iff simply implies here that he will not under any circumstances buy her a dress if she doesn't get good grades. An IF statement here would imply leniency, i.e. even if she doesn't get good grades, he might buy her the dress without committing a logical error.

Comment: "Only if" is the informal name for ["Logical implication"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication). Actualy, "if" is also a logical implication, with the propositions reversed

Answer (score 5):

No :P

"Only If" is not a stronger version of "If" that keeps what it implies.

This is the illustration for the two equivalent statements:

- Yell only if I fall.
- If you yell, I must have fallen. (Notice the subtlety. I didn't say "I fall if you yell". This is logical deduction, not cause-effect.)

Each circle represents a set of instances of "I fall" or "Yell".

Disclaimer: English is not my first language. I'm only talking about the mathematical sense.

[image]

Comment: `"Only If" is not a restriction of "If"` - I think you'll find it is (and *especially* in a mathematical sense)! "Yell if I fall" (note the missing "only") leaves the option for the person being instructed to yell at *other* things, thus them yelling *doesn't* necessarily imply you have fallen. This clearly doesn't match your Venn diagram, as the "Yell" would have an area outside of "Fall".

Comment: Oops sorry. I was confused. Thanks DMA57361. What I had in my mind was `"Only If" was not a stronger version of "If" that still kept the meaning of "If" in a stricter sense`.

Answer (score 1):

If I said

> Yell if I fall

then that would mean that I am asking to yell in the event of me falling, but you can still yell for other reasons. I can also flip this. The rather awkward sentence

> I fall only if you yell

means the same thing as the former because "A if B" is the same thing as "B only if A", hence the arrow notation B => A and A <= B. If I did in fact fall, then it is guaranteed that you yelled, but if you yelled, then I didn't necessarily have to fall.

> Yell only if I fall

This means that the only reason for you to yell is me falling, but if I do fall, then you don't necessarily have to yell. This is the same as saying

> I fall if you yell

Meaning that if you yell, then I am guaranteed to fall, but I can still fall without you yelling.

> Yell if and only if I fall

This means that the only reason for you to yell is me falling, but you have to yell if I do fall. You are guaranteed to yell if I fall, and I am guaranteed to fall if you yell.

---

It occurs to me that there is an allowance for ambiguity in the common world. Even if you say **if**, then one can generally deduce that you do actually mean **only if** (or maybe even **if and only if**).

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> Would the person have to yell once I fell?

Yes, the person *would* yell once you fell, but only if you fell.

"If" and "Only if" used in the same way means the same thing, except that "only if" is more forceful, more compelling.

"If and only if" is the most obligatory of the three, in which the action has been distinguished and emphasised, "If, and *only if*" It's the most forceful of the three

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, it's an ambiguous command, and if you really want to be clear in your request, you would phrase it in an unambiguous way.

Technically speaking... well, who cares? The goal of language is to communicate with humans. There may be some arcane rules of language that provide for a definitive answer to your question, but since few people are familiar with it, knowing the rule won't do you any good.

Edit: First time visiting/posting so I'm not sure how this community leans between looking for technical grammar rules as opposed to practicality. In real life and in a lot of writing I find "Just say what you mean in a way that people will understand you!" to be the underlying answer to a lot of grammatical questions. Since I've been downvoted already, I can see that at least one person prefers the former.

Answer (score -2):

- > Yell if I fall.

  You want him to yell if you fall. No guarantee he will yell if you fall. You don't mind if he yells for any other reason.
- > Yell only if I fall.

  You want him only to yell if you fall. No other reason. No guarantee he will yell if you fall, but if he yells, you want him only to have done so if you have fallen. You don't want him to yell for any other reason.
- > Yell if and only if I fall.

  Same as "only if". Redundant. Why mathematicians/logicians insist on the "if and only if" phrase is paradoxical because it is inelegant (redundant).

Comment: It is only redundant because you misinterpret it. You say it's the same as "only if". But it is not. "Only if", as you say, means "no guarantee he will yell if you fall". The first *if* provides just that guarantee. In other words, 3 is a combination of 1 and 2, and you simply failed to combine your correct reasoning for 1 and 2 into the correct reasoning for 3. But anyway, all of this has been covered in the top and accepted answer two years ago.

Comment: In formal logic, case 1 is `Fall => Yell` ("*If I fall, you must yell*"), so a fall *must always* result in a yell. In strict logical terms, your assertion "*No guarantee he will yell if you fall*" is not correct, leading you to misunderstand the strict logical meaning of "if and only if".